# Verifying Stokes' Theorem on two intersecting cylinders

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, surface-integrals

> Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be the portion of the cylinder $y^2 + z^2 = 4$ with $z>0$ and $x^2 + y^2 ≤ 1$. Let $\mathbf{f}(x,y,z) = (zx-y)\mathbf{i}$, where $\mathbf{i}$ is the usual unit vector in the $x$-direction.
>
> Verify that Stokes' Theorem is satisfied in this case.

So this question is in two parts: I first have to evaluate $\iint_S \nabla \times \mathbf{f} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{S}$, then $\oint_{\partial S}\mathbf{f} \cdot \mathrm{d} \mathbf{r}$, and finally show that they are equal.

**My Attempt**

I first calculated $\nabla \times \mathbf{f}$ to be $\begin{vmatrix}\
\mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\
(zx-y) & 0 & 0\\
\end{vmatrix} = (0,x,1).$

I then parameterised the cylinder by $\mathbf{r}(\theta,z) = (\cos\theta,\sin\theta,z)$ , with my normal $\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial \theta} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial z} = (\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0)$ which is outward pointing as required. And my integral becomes $$\begin{align} \int_{\theta = 0} ^{2\pi}\int_{z=0}^{\sqrt{4-\sin^2\theta}}(0,\cos\theta,1)\cdot(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0)\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}\theta & = \int_{\theta = 0} ^{2\pi}\int_{z=0}^{\sqrt{4-\sin^2\theta}}\sin\theta\cos\theta\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}\theta\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\theta = 0} ^{2\pi}\sin2\theta\sqrt{4-\sin^2\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta\end{align}$$ at which point I am stuck.
I think perhaps my parameterisation is wrong, or maybe I have to calculate the surface integrals in two steps, but the latter method didn't seem to work either and I can't find any better parameterisations.

I also am having trouble on how to parameterise the line integral I need to compute. Should there be two boundaries which I need to combine to find the whole boundary $\partial S$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that due to the periodicity of the integrand we have

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sin \theta \cos \theta \sqrt{4-\sin^2 \theta} \, d\theta=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin \theta \cos \theta \sqrt{4-\sin^2 \theta} \, d\theta$$

Further note that the integrand is an odd function of $\theta$ and therefore the integral is identically zero.

---

The integral of interest should be

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \nabla \times \vec f(\rho, \theta,z(\rho,\theta)) \cdot\hat n \frac{\rho d\rho d\theta}{(\hat n \cdot \hat z)}$$

The curl of $\vec f$ is $\nabla \times \vec f=\hat yx +\hat z$ while the unit normal $\hat n$ to the surface of the cylinder is $\hat n=\frac12(\hat yy+\hat zz)$ since $\sqrt{y^2+z^2}=2$.  Finally, note that

$$dS=\frac{dxdy}{(\hat z \cdot \hat n)}=\frac{dxdy}{\frac12 z}$$

Thus, we have

$$\begin{align}
\hat n \cdot \nabla \times \vec f dS&= \frac12(xy+z) \frac{dxdy}{\frac12 z}\\\\
&=\left(\frac{xy}{\sqrt{4-y^2}}+1\right)dxdy\\\\
&=\left(\frac{\rho^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2 \sin^2 \theta}}+1\right)\rho d\rho d\theta
\end{align}$$

Thus we have 
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \nabla \times \vec f(\rho, \theta,z(\rho,\theta)) \cdot\hat n \frac{\rho d\rho d\theta}{(\hat n  \cdot \hat z)}=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \left(\frac{\rho^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2 \sin^2 \theta}}+1\right) \rho d\rho d\theta$$

The first term integrates to zero since it has period $2\pi$ in $\theta$ and is an odd function of $\theta$.  The second term is trivial to integrate and yields $\pi$.

Let's verify this by carrying out the line integral.  The parameterization is $x=\cos \theta$, $y =\sin \theta$, and $z=\sqrt{4-\sin^2 \theta}$ with $\theta$ going from $-\pi$ to $\pi$.  On the contour of interest, $d\vec l=\hat \theta d\theta$.  Thus,

$$\begin{align}
\int_C \vec f \cdot d\vec l &=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left(zx-y\right)\hat x\cdot \hat \theta d\theta\\\\
&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left(\sqrt{4-\sin^2 \theta}\cos \theta-\sin \theta\right)(-\sin \theta) d\theta\\\\
&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left(-\sin \theta \cos \theta \sqrt{4-\sin^2 \theta}+\sin^2 \theta\right) d\theta\\\\
&=\pi
\end{align}$$

since the first integral is an odd in $\theta$ and the second integral trivially integrates to $\pi$.

Comment: This I follow, but is the method preceeding this correct? And do you have any tips on how to approach the line integral to show that Stokes' Theorem does indeed apply?

Comment: I believe that there was a misinterpretation of the surface integral in the original OP.  The surface is the cylinder $y^2+z^2=4$ and the domain in the $x-y$ plane is $x^2+y^2\le 1$.

Comment: Thanks very much! All this is very clear to me except your use of parameterisation and the limits you got for the surface integral at the beginning of your edit. Where did you pull this from?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  I added some more explanation on the surface integral.  The one thing to remember is that $dS\ne dxdy$ in general.  When one projects a surface $z=z(x,y)$ onto the $x-y$ plane, one needs to scale $dxdy$ since heuristically $dxdy/dS=\cos \gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the angle made between the surface normal and the normal to the $x-y$ plane (i.e, $\hat z$).  Thus, $dS = dxdy/(\hat n \cdot \hat z)$.